# Where CLAUSE and NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following columns

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| Account | Employee |   Org    |
+---------+----------+----------+
|     123 | ABC      | Gold     |
|     234 | PQR      | Silver   |
|     456 | XYZ      |          |
|     567 | MNQ      | Gold     |
|     714 | RPT      | Platinum |
|     819 | MKQ      | BRONZE   |
|     100 | LPA      | Tin      |
|     101 | QRT      |          |
|     104 | LMY      | Platinum |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Now the intention is to filter out all employees who have ORG like Bronze or Tin
Straight forward this is with query;

```
Select * from table 1 where Org NOT IN ('Bronze','Tin')
```

However this will filter records which have ORG as NULL which i don't want.
So basically above query gives me;

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| Account | Employee |   Org    |
+---------+----------+----------+
|     123 | ABC      | Gold     |
|     234 | PQR      | Silver   |
|     567 | MNQ      | Gold     |
|     714 | RPT      | Platinum |
|     104 | LMY      | Platinum |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Where as i want;

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| Account | Employee |   Org    |
+---------+----------+----------+
|     123 | ABC      | Gold     |
|     234 | PQR      | Silver   |
|     456 | XYZ      |          |
|     567 | MNQ      | Gold     |
|     714 | RPT      | Platinum |
|     101 | QRT      |          |
|     104 | LMY      | Platinum |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

I could get this result by replacing NULL with some values with case statement and then filter records but i think there must be more clean and easy way of doing this?

My Current Query;

```
Select * from (
 select ACCOUNT , EMPLOYEE , 
       CASE WHEN ORG IS NULL THEN 'RETAIN'
       ELSE ORG END AS EORG FROM table1 ) P
       WHERE P.EORG not in ('Bronze','Tin')
```

Is there better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add `NULL` to the whitelist:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE Org NOT IN ('Bronze', 'Tin') OR Org IS NULL;
```

Comment: I was thinking of checking for `isnull(org,'') not in ('bronze','tin')` but that might have issues with using the index on org, so yours while longer is better. Upvoted.

Comment: @TomC Yeah...that idea also crossed my mind, but I would paranoid that somehow the coalesced value might also appear as actual data somewhere else.

Comment: Its a `not in` so wouldn't matter. But there's probably an index on org and don't want to make that difficult.

Comment: I would check `IS NULL` before `NOT IN(...)`

Comment: Intention was for me to learn if there was better way of filtering out those records and this works fraction of second faster then case statement...i will now test on full DB records :)

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is null will return false when compared to anything else, even another null. The result of false survives all the way out to the top level; you can't turn it around with NOT

This is false:

```
'X' = null
```

This is also false:

```
NOT ('X' = null)
```

And this is false:

```
 null IN ('X', null)
```

This too:

```
null NOT IN('x', null)
```

It may seem counterintuitive at first but these are the rules. You can only ever specifically test whether something is or isn't null with

```
something IS NULL
something IS NOT NULL
```

So either cater for nulls specifically or convert them to something real before you compare:

```
Select * from table where column not in (...) or column is null

Select * from table where coalesce(column, 'x') not in (...)
```

For the second form to work, whatever you put in the coalesce (I put x) should not appear in the IN list (otherwise it IS IN and will hence be filtered out), nor should it ever appear in the data. The first form would be preferred as not all databases will successfully use an index on the column if coalesce is used

Side point, when posting on stack overflow please prefix your code lines with 4 blank spaces - it will then show in a grey box in a mono space font and multiple spaces are preserved (you've used quotes, yellow box, no monospace, can make things harder to read)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way [IN operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql) works. On that page is a large caution...

> Any null values returned by *subquery* or *expression* that are compared to *test_expression* using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.

Try this..

```
WHERE P.EORG <> 'Bronze' and P.EORG <> 'Tin'
```

Answer (score 0):

You May Simply use ISNULL function in your query

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ISNULL(Org,'') NOT IN ('Bronze', 'Tin')

Answer (score -2):

Try to do as this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [dbo].[stockmaster] 
WHERE  openingweight NOT IN ( '10' ) OR openingweight IS NULL
```